# How to simple secure APIs on App Engine with API key?

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, swagger, openapi, google-app-engine-python

I am looking to secure my API endpoints so that only authorized apps can access or write to it. My stack:

1. Flask (API is built on a Flask-Restplus/Flask-Restless equivalent)
2. GCP - App Engine Standard

My main need is to secure the API so that unauthorized parties cannot make requests against my endpoints such as `https://api.example.com/v1/fruits/1`. I came across GCP's [Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/), whose API Key security model is based on OpenAPI (Swagger). Much as Google seems to [discourage it](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/when-why-api-key#security_of_api_keys), using a key should work for my use case (though I'll probably eventually need to tighten it by adding token-based auth) - it's a good start.

I have followed the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine#python) on how to set up API keys on App Engine and have hit an issue with *specifying the 'paths' property dynamically* (instead of hardcoding them all in, as I have a lot of routes and am using Flask-Rest* extensions. That is, I already defined the routes so *I don't want to define them again on the swagger config file*). I have tried the following on the 'paths' property:

1. Leave property undefined/empty. Leads to the deployment error: `Invalid OpenAPI file. Please fix the schema errors:\nerror: object has missing required properties ([\"paths\"])`
2. Use 'wildcard' syntax matching like below. Error: `Please fix the schema errors:\nerror: instance type (null) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: [\"object\"])`

[image: wildcard matching on paths]

The question: **what is the scalable way to apply the API key requirement to all my routes without re-declaring all the routes on the OpenAPI config file?** *I'm not trying to use OpenAPI to create an API*, just looking to use a key/secret here.

Alternatively, is there an easier way to secure endpoints when using GAE/GCP or Flask that I'm missing out on? I feel that this is such a common problem and imagine some kind of a drop-in solution exists out there

More background info

- I looked at this username+password, token-based [Flask-auth tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask). Unfortunately, my mobile & web apps (API clients) use federated Firebase auth so we don't have username/password support to generate tokens. It also seems like reinventing the wheel
- [Swagger 3](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/api-keys/) notes on API keys

Comment: When you say "I'm not trying to use OpenAPI to create an API, just looking to use a key/secret here." I assume you are not using Cloud Endpoints. Are you using App Engine solely to deploy your API? If so, you cannot use API keys to protect an App Engine app according to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys).

Comment: @dhauptman Yes I'm only using GAE to deploy & host the API. I was hoping to use Cloud Endpoints to secure my API, seeing from https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/ that it allows "Control who has access to your API and validate every call with JSON Web Tokens and Google API keys". What other strategies do you recommend so only my apps (native mobile & web) have access to my API?

Answer (score 0):

The best recommendation is to use [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine-standard) since you'll have a lot more options to manage and secure your APIs.

If for any reason you don't want to use Endpoints you have some authentication options for GAE:

GAE with Service to Service authentication, check [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/appidentity/),

GAE with User authentication, check [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/authenticating-users).

You can also protect your applications and resources using [Cloud IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/app-engine-quickstart).

Comment: I have looked into Cloud Endpoints and actually want to use it, but ran into the specific issue I've described in the post. How can I use Endpoints + OpenAPI (API key option) without having to manually declare [redefine] all my paths in the openapi-gae.yaml?

Comment: According to [Restplus documentation](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/swagger.html#export-swagger-specifications) you can export the Swagger specifications that are auto generated from your annotations, so you don't need to hard code the specification. You may also be interested in [this document](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/swagger.html#documenting-authorizations) on how to define api keys using Restplus.